# Could you fit a Borg cube in the Voth city-ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

Would the Voth city-ship be able to hold a Borg cube inside of it? It's obvious it would be able to hold hundreds of Galaxy-class ships or even a few Deep Space Nines, so would it be able to fit a Borg cube?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Probably not

On [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_cube), a Borg Cube is described as:

> Borg cubes were massive in size, **measuring over three kilometers across**

(Which would be each direction)

Whilst [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Voth_City_Ship) says the Voth City ship measured over 4.9 km in length.

Looking at [this size comparison chart](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/comparison/stations.png), we see that the Borg Cube is substantially taller than the Voth City ship:

Comment: It would be interesting to see how a Borg cube would react in that situation

Comment: It could fit a Borg scout  sphere possibly a tactical sphere

Comment: @Darren indeed, but not a proper full-sized cube

Comment: @Darren: I think it's pretty clear how a Borg cube would react in that situation. Assimilate all the things.

Comment: @Ellesedil yeah the cube would be affected by the dampening filed

Comment: @Darren: That's unknown. Sure, we know that the dampening field affected Voyager. But, the Voth would need to have a dampening field that would interact with and disrupt the Borg's systems, not to mention that the Borg are highly adaptable. Also, it would need to disable the drones, since they are the ones that would be doing the assimilating.

Comment: @Ellesedil yeah that's a very good point

Answer (score 25):

## **No**

This picture comparing the two, both at depicted at the same scale, 1 pixel to 10 meters, should help to answer:

[image: Cube vs Voth City Ship]

And with the two overlaid:

[image: VothShipOverlayCube]

These images are from the excellent [Jeff Russells Starship Comparison Guide](http://www.merzo.net/indexSD.html)

The figures used to create these images to scale are from [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_cube) - citing the Cubes size as:

> *...measuring over three kilometers across and possessing an internal volume of 27 cubic kilometers.*
>
> <sub>***VOY: "Dark Frontier"***</sub>

And [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Voth_City_Ship) - citing the Voth City Ship as 4,900m long

Even though this only confirms length, the to scale drawings show clearly that, despite being long enough, the Borg Cube would not fit inside the Voth City Ship as it is far too tall.

---

### **For Deep Space 9**

You *might* be able to squeeze 1 DS9 into the Voth City Ship if you got the angles right, and if the Voth City ship is wider than it is tall, which it appears to be. If you took the pylons off or pushed them down you could fit many more in.

Again to scale with each other at 1 pixel to 10 meters.

[image: VothCityShipVsDS9]

And overlaid

[image: VothCityDS9Overlay]

Size of DS9 as given in [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Space_9)

> *Rick Sternbach's drawings for a four-foot miniature (six-foot as built) specify a scale of 70 feet to an inch, resulting in a conceptual diameter of roughly 3,360 feet (1,024 meters).*
>
> *The visual effects department used 5,280 feet (precisely one mile or 1,609 meters).*
>
> *For Star Trek: Deep Space Nine Technical Manual, Sternbach compromised at 1,451.82 meters (4,763.19 feet), although the new size matches only Doug Drexler's images of the exterior in the book, not his cutaways which depict a smaller station.*

Comment: The other chart, shows the voth ship to be a lot longer

Comment: @Darren The other chart (I assume you mean the one on the other answer) has the Voth City Ship at twice the size (9,800m) as the size given in Memory Beta that myself, the Starship Chart and the other answer reference. The other answer seems to be using two different lengths for the Voth City ship.

Comment: Odd, that should really be "_possessing an internal volume of **over** 27 cubic kilometres._" Even a small amount over 3 kilometres in each direction makes a large increase in volume. If a Borg Cube was 3.11 km (not much over 3 km), its volume would be 30 cubic km.

Comment: @CJDennis it should, or it should say "measuring 3 Kilometres..." bad writing from the Voyager team it seems

Comment: Both the city ship and deep space 9 seem *very* small.

Comment: @Axelrod but they are the sizes given from within the series or the creators of the models. So not really sure how to answer when in universe and WOG are used for the sizes

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn Oh, no, I believe the measurements! I just mean that it's weird for space stations that are supposed to hold cities' worth of people to be smaller than an average small town.

Comment: @Axelrod oh yes I was surprised too. DS9 looks tiny especially when the pylons are removed. But then as more of a star wars fan I'm used to expecting things to be bigger. Was shocked how big the cube was too.

Comment: At least B5 had some concrete measurements. 5 miles 2.5 million tons

Comment: @JeremyFrench love babylon 5